# Inquiry: Why is this hashtable breaking on me?

Tags: java, debugging, key, hashtable

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of the code I have written below. See:

```
Set<String> keys = hashmap.keySet();
Iterator<String> keyiterator = keys.iterator();
while(keyiterator.hasNext()) {
    out = "";
    String s = keyiterator.next();
    ArrayList<String> temp = hashmap.get(s);

    out = out + temp.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < temp.size(); i ++)
    {
        String s1 = temp.get(i);
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\[\\[", "");
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\]\\]", "");
        s1 = s1.trim();
        System.out.println(s1);

        ArrayList<String> temp2 = hashmap.get(s1);

        if(temp2 != null) out = out + " " + temp2.get(0);
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

**Note:**

The hashmap is of form `<String, ArrayList<String>>`

The ArrayList has a numeric value at position 0. For example,

```
Key = Doc1  List = 0, Poland, Iceland, Candy
Key = Doc2  List = 1, UK, Yule
Key = Poland List = 2, Doc1, Doc2
Key = Iceland List = 3, Doc1, Poland
```

Every list entry contains at least the number entry.

**Problem:**

This `ArrayList<String> temp = hashmap.get(s);` returns list for the entry. 
But  `ArrayList<String> temp2 = hashmap.get(s1);`returns null for the entry. In other words, the list is empty.

**Question:** 
Simply put. Why? The list of strings once we have stripped the left and right square (see the replaceALL portion of the code above) are keynames in the hashtable. I have tried this:

```
ArrayList<String> temp2 = hashmap.get("poland");
```

where "poland" is a known document/key word for the hashtable. But it returns nothing. However, as a sanity check, if I put `ArrayList<String> temp2 = hashmap.get(s);` so it is looking at the key I used above once more, it can find that key value a second time just fine.

Can someone please explain to me what is going wrong? I promise to give rep to anyone who replies meaningful to my question.

Comment: It would have helped alot if you'd included an SSCCE.

Comment: I strongly support the suggestion of including an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Almost certainly, the problem is in something you are assuming outside what you have posted. The act of producing an SSCCE may directly solve the problem, by showing a dependency on something you don't think is relevant. If it does not, posting the SSCCE will enable debug by others.

Comment: If this was SSCCE, honestly I would not be asking this question. I am dealing with a 3K size hashtable. The above example captures the essence of my question. If s1 was returning like I wished, for example  hashmap.get("poland") should return  2, Doc1, Doc2. However, I get null. Hence, my question. I respectfully feel SSCCE is missing the point of my question here.

Comment: "If this was an SSCCE, honestly I would not be asking this question."  Isn't that the point?  "The above example captures the essence of my question."  Given that the problem was how you were populating your hashmap, and David Wallace's answer was made incorrect by your edit, I would say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are doing some trimming of extra characters on your `ArrayList`. Could it be that your key values and your `ArrayList` values are getting trimmed in different ways?

For example: `s1 = "Poland"` but the actual key in the hashtable, that is your s, is `s = "  Poland  "` ?

Comment: You understood my problem well. I am trying to get s1 = "poland" to recognize. I trimmed s1, but it didn't work. I tried for s and it didn't work. I trimmed my keys when I created the hashtable and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. When you said it was returning null, my first thought was that they key values weren't matching somehow. Glad my suggestions helped.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're getting a value out of one of the `ArrayList` objects (such as `"Poland"`, `"Iceland"` etc), then looking for an entry in the map that has that value as its *key*.  But the keys are `"Doc1"`, `"Doc2"` and so on, not `"Poland"` and `"Iceland"`.

Comment: Thanks. I modified my example hashtable so I am more clear in communicating what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the former (`ArrayList<String> temp = hashmap.get(s)`) works because that is the key, as shown here:

```
String s = keyiterator.next();
```

Also,

> "...returns null for the entry. In other words, the list is empty."

I would disagree with this. It only returns null if you use a key that doesn't exist in the map.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I did that as a sanity check. I realize this, but I was wondering why s1 value doesn't work as well?

Comment: @GeekyOmega Well, does `s.equals(s1)` return true?

Comment: It shouldn't. Let me explain more. s is some key such as "Poland". We then get that keys list of strings. We iterate through them. s1 is some string from that iteration. s1 could be the value "Doc1" and we want to get the first value in the ArrayList, the number, for "Doc1". Which if you look above in the example, should be 0.